# How's GNU extended function running when didn't defined _GNU_SOURCE

Tags: gcc, compilation, gnu, cpu-architecture, glibc

I test GNU extended function such as "wcstoq" at different platforms.
At first,I didn't compile the testcase with D_GNU_SOURCE，so I got a compile warning as follows:

```
wcstoq.c:31:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'wcstoq'; did you mean 'wcstol'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     retval=wcstoq(nptr,endptr,base);
            ^~~~~~
            wcstol
```

when I use gdb to debug this testcase,it goes into the correct function which is same as the case I defined _GNU_SOURCE.
But the function goes wrong when I did't define _GNU_SOURCE.

for example:

When I test the out of range case in x86_64, it should set `retval= LLONG_MAX(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)`,but it actually set `retval= -1(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)`.
The result also confused me when I test it in other platforms ppc, it actually set `retval=0x000000007FFFFFFF`.
when I defined `_GNU_SOURCE`, function runs ok in x86_64 and ppc, it both returns `LLONG_MAX(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)`.

my question is:

1 Why when I don't define `_GNU_SOURCE`,but gcc still can find the right function？

2 Why the fuction failed even the gcc find the right one,and in some cases the function can still be used,but in other cases it goes wrong？

3 Why the failed result of fuction is different in different platforms, how architecture platforms or other factors impact the different results？

4 The right way to use GNU extend function？

Thks!

Comment: There's no *prototype* definition in the case you've shown, so the compile does not know the sizes (or numbers) of parameters.  The *external* symbol exists, since it is not a macro or inline.

Comment: I think the best answer to 4) is that you *should* define `_GNU_SOURCE` to get the library headers to include prototypes for GNU extensions.  Without declarations at all, the compiler assumes the return type is `int`.

Comment: Thanks,@PeterCordes，Do you know any more information about the behavior of function with implicit declaration, not only the return type but also some input or output parameters, is it mean the behavior of this function is unpredictable or undefined?Especially for GNU extended functions?

Comment: Thanks,@ThomasDickey but what I am confused and curious about why the function could also be called even if not defined _GNU_SOURCE，and why the behavior or output of the function is not the same in different platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit function declarations, a GCC extension which is enabled by default, use a return type of `int`, however the function is defined as returning `long long`.  With such a type mismatch, anything can happen.  In practice, the results depend on the calling convention, and that is why they vary across architectures.

You should really compile with `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` (or use C++).  Implicit function declarations were removed from C close to twenty years ago (in ISO/IEC 9899:1999), but we still cannot change the GCC default because too many autoconf checks would break, resulting in software accidentally losing features.

(I think you meant to write `retval` in your question instead of `errno`.)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning explicitly that implicit declarations are allowed in ISO C89.  But yes, in later ISO C standards (and C++) it's not allowed, and agreed that it's generally a bad idea.  There's a reason GCC warns about it even without `-Wall`.